# Why does TaskFactory.StartNew in combination with Task.ContinueWith work?

Tags: task-parallel-library, taskfactory

[TaskFactory.StartNew()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx) creates a new Task, starts it and then returns it. I suppose that it is safe to assume that the following code will always work (since it was taken from MSDN):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("first"))
   .ContinueWith(antecendent => Console.WriteLine("second"));
```

How does this work? How can I be assured that the task hasn't been started (or even completed) before `.ContinueWith()` is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TPL is intended to abstract the asynchronous nature of the tasks from the consumer, so if you call `ContinueWith` on a completed task then the antecedent handler will be invoked immediately.

This means that you can create a `Task` with `TaskFactory.StartNew` (which will schedule the task to run asynchronously) or `new Task(() => { /*...*/})` followed by `task.RunSynchronously()` and you can always call `ContinueWith` on the `Task`.  It basically means "schedule this to run once the task is completed, or now if it is already finished".